# training CNN model using word2vectorization,while invoking get_vector() .Showing error " KeyError: 'CALLDATASIZE' " while preparing train_x

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, word2vec, smartcontracts

set of word vectors are generated from github link:https://github.com/jianwei76/SoliAudit/blob/master/va/features/op.origin.csv.xz.

Converted this op.origin.csv.xz file to .txt file using gen_doc() function,

````
    opfile=op.origin.csv.xz #downloaded and uploaded in google colab folder
    binfile=model.bin # new binfile created to save the model generated from word2vec model

    def op_name(op):
        return op.rstrip('0123456789') 
    
    def filter_op(op_line):
        filter_ops = [ op_name(op) for op in op_line.split() ]
        return ' '.join(filter_ops)
    
    def gen_doc(opfile, docfile):
        op = pd.read_csv(opfile, compression='xz', index_col=0)
        op.dropna(inplace=True)
        op['Opcodes'] = op['Opcodes'].apply(filter_op)
    
    def get_model(opfile, binfile, size=5):
       docfile = 'op-doc.tmp.txt'
       gen_doc(opfile, docfile)
       logging.info('Training opcode word2vec...in=%s, out=%s, word-embed-size=%d' % (docfile, binfile, size))
       word2vec.word2vec(docfile, binfile, size=size, verbose=True)
         
    return word2vec.load(binfile)
    ```
    
    
    For the Code snippet:
    ``` 
    op_vecs = [ opline_to_vec(row['Opcodes'], w2v) for idx, row in data.iterrows() ]
    ```
    invokes function
    ```
        def opline_to_vec(line, w2v):
            print('inside oplinetovec func')
            ops = line.split()
            print('ops and line.split done')
            vec = np.zeros((len(ops), w2v.vectors.shape[1]))
            print('vec computed')
            for i, op in enumerate(ops):
                print('each vec i values')
                vec[i] = w2v.get_vector(op_name(op))***
                print(vec[i])
    
            print ('returning from opline_to_vec')    
            return vec
````

the output of op-doc-temp.txt-->

```
    CALLDATASIZE SUB DUP ADD SWAP DUP DUP CALLDATALOAD PUSH AND SWAP PUSH ADD SWAP SWAP SWAP SWAP POP POP POP PUSH JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH MLOAD DUP DUP DUP MSTORE PUSH ADD SWAP POP POP PUSH MLOAD DUP SWAP SUB SWAP RETURN JUMPDEST PUSH PUSH DUP CALLDATASIZE SUB DUP ADD SWAP DUP DUP CALLDATALOAD PUSH AND SWAP PUSH ADD SWAP SWAP SWAP SWAP DUP CALLDATALOAD SWAP PUSH ADD SWAP DUP ADD DUP CALLDATALOAD SWAP PUSH ADD SWAP SWAP SWAP SWAP SWAP SWAP SWAP SWAP SWAP POP POP POP PUSH JUMP JUMPDEST STOP JUMPDEST CALLVALUE DUP ISZERO PUSH JUMPI PUSH DUP REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH PUSH DUP
```

I have highlighted the code snippet(vec[i] = w2v.get_vector(op_name(op))) which produces the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/word2vec/wordvectors.py in ix(self, word)
     36         Returns the index on `self.vocab` and `self.vectors` for `word`
     37         """
---> 38         return self.vocab_hash[word]
     39 
     40     def word(self, ix):


KeyError: 'CALLDATASIZE'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzx7z.jpg)

It would be really great if you could please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're asking a word-vectors model for the vector of a word, `'CALLDATASIZE'`, that it does not know.

Where did the set of word-vectors come from? (Did you train them yourself, or import them from elsewhere? How did you load them?)

Would you expect it to have a vector for that weird opcode-word? If so, skip the other wraparound steps and just check for that word, and go back to the prior steps that you thought should have created that word-vector.

If it's reasonable the set doesn't have that word, and you can't fix that gap, change your code to handle that case - perhaps by ignoring the word.

Comment: Thankyou for all of your replies.. I was checking the code and examined the bin file which was outputted from the word2vec model. When i outputted binfile.vocab many words first letter was not there.  eg, for PUSH word --> binfile.vocab output 'USH', for word 'LOAD' it is outputting as 'OAD'

Comment: word2vec model ``` word2vec.word2vec(docfile, binfile, size=size, verbose=True)``` .binfile vocab as  ```binfile.vocab```. why the vocab is skipping the first letter of the words. docfile content is ``` 'CALLDATASIZE', 'CALLDATALOAD', 'REVERT', 'CALLVALUE', 'ADD', 'SUB', 'ADD', 'REVERT', 'CALLDATALOAD', 'ADD', .... 'SHA3', 'CALLER' ```.but binfile.vocab output is ```'</s>' '076605' 'USH' '.211938' 'DUP' '320594' 'WAP' '142392' 'POP' 'TURNDATASIZE' '400776' 'T' '.412049' 'R' '959537' 'CALL' '11.562811' ``` Why  difference in word vocab of  binfile. Your input would be very much helpful

Comment: Where did the set of word-vectors come from? Did you train them yourself, or import them from elsewhere? How did you load them? What is this 'binfile' you've mentioned – how was it created, and how are you lookinng at it now? (It will be far easier to understand formatted code or data if you edit it as updates into your question than try to fit it in these unformatted comments.)

Comment: I have edited and updated the question to indicate how word vectors are imported, github link is given, how it is converted from.xz file to .txt is also given. how it is loaded and binfile stored the model trained from word2vec. how it is invoked is also shown in the edited qn. Thankyou so much for your replies ..

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure your `op-doc-temp.txt` is in the right format for the `word2vec` library you're using? Which library are you using, and how did you install it?

Comment: I kind of  got a solution . As you told the input in op-doc-tem.txt was not according to how it is shown. So resolved it  by following the steps of the link" https://www.kaggle.com/code/rajmehra03/a-complete-text-classfication-guide-word2vec-lstm/notebook". uploaded a bin file and it worked fine. Thankyou so much for your insights @gojomo